# How to return a GraphQL error in graphql-tools addMockFunctionsToSchema?

Tags: apollo-client, graphql-tools

I'd like to mock an error response in `graphql-tools/addMockFunctionsToSchema` mock resolver following this [pattern](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#graphql-resolvers):

```
const mocks = {
  ...,
  Mutation: () => ({
    getToken: (_, { password }) => {
      if (password === 'password') {
        return { value: casual.uuid }
      } else {
        throw new Error('Incorrect email or password')
      }
    }
  })
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({`
  type Token { value: ID! }
  type Mutation {
     getToken(email: String!, password: String!): Token
  }
`});

addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema, mocks});
```

This works OK and does return a GraphQL error but:

1. It looks like it's only returning an error because it's an internal server error, throwing on this [line](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/5c5418cec88f1d5520eccc1d2e6dfaa511547e4d/src/mock.ts#L202).
2. I'd like to mock an actual GraphQL error response indicating that the user input was invalid

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking into this issue today.
It turns out that you should just return the error instead of throwing one.

```js
  Mutation: () => ({
    getToken: (_, { password }) => {
      if (password === 'password') {
        return { value: casual.uuid }
      } else {
        return new Error('Incorrect email or password')
      }
    }
  })
```